# Can special characters or any non UTF-8 characters be encrypted with AES-128/256?

Tags: android, encryption, character-encoding, aes

My customers are complaining that they cannot login using my app.

My Android app uses AES256 encryption when sending users data to the server.

Is it possible that certain characters cannot be encrypted / decrypted such as special characters, non UTF-8 characters, etc?

Comment: What is your runtime environment on both sides? Are you using an application server on Windows maybe?

Comment: What do you mean with "non-UTF-8" characters? UTF-8 is a complete encoding scheme of Unicode code points. As long as the character is in Unicode, you can encode it using UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES just encrypts bytes. It doesn't care what those bytes represent. Therefore, if there are problems sending non-ASCII characters, for example, the issue is likely to be in how you are encoding those characters into bytes, not with AES itself.

Comment: And the AES-encrypted data (even if it was valid UTF-8 before encryption) may well not be correct if treated as UTF-8.  It may well contain lots of byte sequences that are not valid as UTF-8.

Comment: Indeed that would cause problems. More subtle corruption could occur if it was interpreted as e.g. UTF-16.